# kernel panic on boot

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, kernel, lenovo

I'm having some trouble booting ubuntu 14.04.

The most weird thing is that after the kernel panic error shows up, if I restart the laptop, grub appears (not showing up when the panic occurred), and if I select "advanced options" and choose to start recovery mode of the current linux image and run a package repair and after apparently not doing anything, if I restart, it boots normally.

Anyways I don't want to do this every time I want to boot my ubuntu. Any help would be grateful.

I'm adding some pictures:

[image]

[image]

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2w3g360VqNWYU1EWFUtWVdzTDQ&usp=sharing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the system stops unexpectedly, it will automatically bring up the GRUB screen on next boot to provide the user with safe error handing methods. But you should be able to just select the Ubuntu entry to continue the boot process. **What yo're describing is a symptom, not the error**. You have to find out what causes the kernel panic in order to prevent it from reoccuring. To help you with that, more information is required, e.g. what did you do before, when exactly does it occur...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to the kernel panic you have, but please try using another server. A more ... "official" one. Changing to default main server is not difficult. Open the **software center** goto **edit** then **software sources** and change the server to main. Then try to update / upgrade again.

Comment: @NikTh I would suggest the same, but looking up information about this mirror brings me to this page: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/sft.if.usp.br-archive

Comment: *"run a package repair"* What do you mean by that or how do you do that? Please be specific. Also have a look at the logs or post them (the latest `/var/log/apt/term.log` and `/var/log/apt/history.log` after the error appears), I'm sure there is something that gives a hint at whats going on.

Comment: @the_Seppi that happens always when I boot my computer. There's nothing weird I do. I Just boot (after repairing packages using grub recovery), then turn off computer, turn on, and bam! error again.

Comment: @NikTh that server is official, but from Brazil. It's the optimal one regarding my location, as per what Ubuntu found.

Comment: @LiveWireBT I will check the logs and post them here, thanks. BTW "packages repair" = in grub system recovery -> option "repair packages".

Comment: I just uploaded some log files. I couldn't find anything exceptional except from syslog file which is showing some call stacks.
Please follow this link: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2w3g360VqNWYU1EWFUtWVdzTDQ&usp=sharing
 to access the files